# How to customize a specific content type display?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, entities

I have a content type which has many fields. My problem is that all fields displays in rows like this picture:
[image]
How can I customize these fields? for example I want them to arrange like this one:
[image]
Also I want to change some font-size (in the red box in second pic). What should I do?
thx.

Comment: what version of drupal are you running?

Comment: Oh! sry, i forgot to mention. I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with the FieldUI, (enable in modules), you can place the fields,
see here `/admin/structure/types`.
with [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) you can even do it more sophisticated.

but in the end you want to have your own theme, or adjust the one your using for css etc.

Comment: There's a great tutorial series for learning Display Suite for D7 here: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648

Comment: There is another excellent tutorial in Drupalcon it was the one that convince me to use display suite http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/take-full-control-your-site-layout-display-suite-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

It seems like CSS Floats can do the job for you. Take a look at [CSS Floats](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) and [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) .